# How to trigger jenkins job using curl and passing parameters in url

Tags: jenkins, build

I am trying to trigger a jenkins build using curl command. Below is my command

```
http://localhost:8080/view/Project%20IRT/job/create_image/buildWithParameters?token=sprit&Action="blah blah"&ClientName="morang"
```

its giving below error and triggering the build with default parameters which i have defined in the job

```
'Action' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'ClientName' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am i missing here.And how to pass  parameters in url for triggering a job.I also tried doing like this but no success below command gives json error.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/view/Project%20IRT/job/create_image/build --data token=sprit --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"Action", "value":"blah blah"},{"name":"ClientName", "value":"morang"}]}'
```

**JSONERROR**;-

```
Caused by: net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of '{parameter:
        at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:499)
        at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:919)
        at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromString(JSONObject.java:1145)
        at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:162)
        at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:132)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.getSubmittedForm(RequestImpl.java:916)
        ... 81 more
</pre></div></div></div><footer><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6" id="footer"></div><div class="col-md-18"><span class="page_generated">Page generated:
 Mar 21, 2016 10:39:05 AM IST</span><span class="rest_api"><a href="api/">REST API</a></span><span class="jenkins_ver"><a href="http://jenkins-ci.org/">Jenkins ver. 1.644</a></span><div
 id="l10n-dialog" class="dialog"></div><div id="l10n-footer" style="display:none; float:left"><a href="#" onclick="return showTranslationDialog();"><img src="/static/fbacd7a6/plugin/tra
nslation/flags.png" />
      Help us localize this page
    </a></div><script>var footer = document.getElementById('l10n-footer');
    var f = document.getElementById('footer');
    f.insertBefore(footer,f.firstChild);
    footer.style.display="block";

    var translation={};
    translation.bundles = "mC177+QPH0ukSUfPbWxfIyQw/DlaO16MmOglhwDdqW6lL/PyzHLaYsioVPvSoTyYFpwCaSkCkRllDVhBqkkft89+rzGakHYKf4ZR3PT0B4HF31sxwlLtogh+g+d5ujrwV53UuNzg67Bb9U4lYNodstxN3fuv/F
cnebyjHpcQPci0zoAkJbd7YJIX3LaNdkuvdoPZmneCtaMjG5camLnbJM+pj9v4BHCQy9gooUl+aIDIuuhLiblKIVXFQfI4UbW2sGYNWluX4qn1iEyeBJGS6kNHKE05r2E5z9X5CVxcvHPb99pTDgBNqhc+WCDdN1d6PM7ueps55Mo/8v5ywsHGE9D
LlfvzHbmfu8Lg+JaQSZK2IKVvN55Ofr9x/4dgeE0khYjkodFSVo8Q/knoFjYZ/tWyIKyXJJrc6OJ40V29iOTF/KNHKFPWZOFueBUyDLiPEClcCMgA6iUB9vbzkFicKLvsTj+cQUAxjzL+8n4Vxh31qmVF/Md+8SdAfI0eau1F";
    translation.detectedLocale = "";

    function showTranslationDialog() {
      if(!translation.launchDialog)
        loadScript("/static/fbacd7a6/plugin/translation/dialog.js");
      else
        translation.launchDialog();
      return false;
    }</script></div></div></div></footer></body></html>curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 2
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 16
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 13
```

Comment: Have you tried using the url http://localhost:8080/job/<projectname> ?

Comment: Nevermind it doesnt matter, i just tried it. Double check the case of your parameters, as its case sensitive. Does it work to trigger from i.e. firefox? Then it might be just an issue with urlencoding on curl.

Comment: do not  know but for some reasons same curl command is working fine from linux OS but giving errors in windows OS.I was running it earlier in windows.

Comment: On windows CMD you need to escape the '%' by prepending another %. so the single % in urlescape need to be changed to %%

Comment: (Reason is that on CMD variables are referenced by %VARIABLE%)

Answer (score 0):

you're just missing escape character before "&". It should be like "^&". This helps me, and works in my case.

So, code will look like:

```
...job/create_image/buildWithParameters?token=sprit&Action="blah blah"^&ClientName="morang"
```